# Is there a way to export shortcuts from Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, keyboard-shortcuts

I have changed the default shortcuts at work and want to synchronize at home.

Is there a way to export and import only the shortcuts?

I'm using Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition.

Answer (score 59):

Try Tools --> Import and Export Settings from Visual Studio.
You can deselect all the options except "All Settings --> Options --> Environment --> Keyboard".

This procedure creates a file .vssettings that you can import at home.

Comment: I think that it will works. I exported right now and will test at home soon.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work for me :( I have comment/uncomment under ctrl + / whereas one of them is texteditor config and other is global one of them was moved properly.

Comment: Worked like a charm on two corporate PCs with Visual Studio 2019, CodeMaid and ReSharper (and as you can imagine a quite long list of custom shortcuts ;)). Thank you!

Comment: @Reven when i use export settings in visual studio installer it doesn't work for me BUT  Go into Visual Studio and select Tools > Import and Export Settings its work. I can try and its work for me