# How can I export my key bindings from Pycharm to VS code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, pycharm, ide, settings, key-bindings

**Would it be possible to export/import my key bindings and other settings to the other IDE?**

My job is working with different IDE's. I'm looking to swap from PyCharm to VS-code because we're working a lot with Azure.

Main features I'm missing now, that I use a lot are:

1. Ctrl + 1 to comment and uncomment a line.
2. F9 to run a line of code,
3. F5 to run the code in a new console
4. shift + F5 to run the code in the same console

There is probably a lot more that I don't know now, but have adjusted over the years. I figured I wasn't the only one with this problem, so I am curious if there is a solution to this.

I have seen so far that you can export your keybindings from PyCharm, but I haven't seen this option for VS Code. Google was not a lot of help.

Comment: even exporting from a Microsoft IDE to another Microsoft IDE is not officially supported: https://stackoverflow.com/q/65998263/11107541.